# Recognizing matrix from image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have written algorithm that solves the pluszle game matrix.
Input is numpy array.

Now I want to recognize the digits of matrix from screenshot.

There are different levels, this is hard one:

[image: there are different levels, this is hard one]

And this is easy one:

[image: this is easy one]

the output of recognition should be numpy array

```
array([[6, 2, 4, 2],
       [7, 8, 9, 7],
       [1, 2, 4, 4],
       [7, 2, 4, 0]])
```

I have tried to feed last image to tesseract

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:/Users/79017/screen_plus.jpg')))
```

The output is unacceptable

```
LEVEL 4

(}00:03 M0
J] —.°—@—@©
```

I think that I should use contours from opencv, because the font is always the same. maybe I should save contours for every digit, than save every countour that exist on screenshot than somehow make matrix from coordinates of every digit-contour. But I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1- Binarize

Tesseract needs you to binarize the image first. No need for contour or any convolution here. Just a threshold should do. Especially considering that you are trying to che... I mean win intelligently to a specific game. So I guess you are open to some ad-hoc adjustments.

For example, `(hard<240).any(axis=2)` put in white (True) everything that is not white on the original image, and black the white parts.

[image]

Note that you don't get the sums (or whatever they are, I don't know what this game is) here. Which are on the contrary almost black areas

But you can have them with another filter

```py
(hard>120).any(axis=2)
```

[image]

You could merge those filters, obviously

```py
(hard<240).any(axis=2) & (hard>120).any(axis=2)
```

[image]

But that may not be a good idea: after all, it gives you an opportunity to distinguish to different kind of data, why you may want to do.

### 2- Restrict

Secondly, you know you are looking for digits, so, restrict to digits. By adding `config='digits'` to your pytesseract args.

```py
pytesseract.image_to_string((hard>240).all(axis=2))
# 'LEVEL10\nNOVEMBER 2022\n\n™\noe\nOs\nfoo)\nso\n‘|\noO\n\n9949 6 2 2 8\n\nN W\nN ©\nOo w\nVon\n+? ah ®)\nas\noOo\n©\n\n \n\x0c'

pytesseract.image_to_string((hard>240).all(axis=2), config='digits')
# '10\n2022\n\n99496228\n\n17\n-\n\n \n\x0c'
```

### 3- Don't use image_to_string

Use `image_to_data` preferably.
It gives you bounding boxes of text.

Or even `image_to_boxes` which give you digits one by one, with coordinates

Because `image_to_string` is for when you have a good old linear text in the image. `image_to_data` or `image_to_boxes` assumes that text is distributed all around, and give you piece of text with position.
`image_to_string` on such image may intervert what you would consider the logical order

### 4- Select areas yourself

Since it is an ad-hoc usage for a specific application, you know where the data are.

For example, your main matrix seems to be in area

```py
hard[740:1512, 132:910]
```

[image]

See

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_boxes((hard[740:1512, 132:910]<240).any(axis=2), config='digits'))
```

Not only it avoids flooding you with irrelevant data. But also, tesseract performs better when called only with an image without other things than what you want to read.

Seems to have almost all your digits here.

### 5- Don't expect for miracles

Tesseract is one of the best OCR. But OCR are not a sure thing...

See what I get with this code (summarizing what I've said so far), printing in red digits detected by tesseract just next to where they were found in the real image.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

hard=cv2.imread("hard.jpg")
hard=hard[740:1512, 132:910]
bin=(hard<240).any(axis=2)
boxes=[s.split(' ') for s in pytesseract.image_to_boxes(bin, config='digits').split('\n')[:-1]]
out=hard.copy() # Just to avoid altering original image, in case we want to retry with other parameters
H=len(hard)
for b in boxes:
     cv2.putText(out, b[0], (30+int(b[1]), H-int(b[2])), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 2)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(out,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, result are fairly good. But there are 5 missing numbers. And one 3 was read as "3.".

For this kind of ad-hoc reading of an app, I wouldn't even use tesseract. I am pretty sure that, with trial and errors, you can easily learn to extract each digits box your self (there are linearly spaced in both dimension).

And then, inside each box, well there are only 9 possible values. Should be quite easy, on a generated image, to find some easy criterions, such as the number of white pixels, number of white pixels in top area, ..., that permits a very simple classification

Comment: NIce answer (I like to see that you provided those illustrations). I think it would be even better if you included a complete script at the end of the answer. Basically just like we require [mcve] in a question. I generally try to do that (it makes it easy for others to validate my clams).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pre-process the image first. By applying a filter, you can, for example, get the contours of an image.

The basic idea of a filter, is to 'slide' some matrix of values over the image, and multiply every pixel value by the value inside the matrix. This process is called **convolution**.

Convolution helps out here, because all irrelevant information is discarded, and thus it is made easier for tesseract to 'read' the image.

This might help you out: https://medium.com/swlh/image-processing-with-python-convolutional-filters-and-kernels-b9884d91a8fd